# Hide and Change Error Messages in wordpress - Big mistake

Tags: php, wordpress

In my functions.php I added the following:

```
// Change Error Messages
function login_error_override()
{
    return 'Username/Password pair not found. Please re-enter or contact the <a href="#">help desk</a>.';
}
add_filter('login_errors', 'login_error_override');
```

The consequences I have after adding this code is that at the registration, some users use an existing username but because this message overrides wordpress original message, they don't get informed about the existence of this username and they never get informed that they have to use a different username.

So, how to customize the registration and login messages?